# How can I reference an (unnumbered) list item?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, itemize

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first item \label{first}

    \item second item
\end{itemize}

In \ref{first} we find the first item.

\end{document}
```

I'd like to reference to an item in the list, but as their isn't a number, I can't use `\label`. Is it possible to add something like `[1]` after the item I'd like to refer to and be able to use `\ref` in order to get this `[1]`? The result should be something like:

*In [1] we find the first item.*

Comment: Is using an `enumerate`-list rather than a `itemize`-list an option? Items in an enumerated lists are easy to cross-referance.

Comment: @Mico: I know, but I prefer using `itemize` in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one option

[image: screenshot]

The idea is create a counter, and then increment (and `\label`) it every time you call `\bulletlabel`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

% set up a counter for bullets
\newcounter{bullet}

% define a command to increment the bullet counter, and label it in one go
\newcommand{\bulletlabel}[1]{\refstepcounter{bullet}\thebullet\label{#1}}

% put [] around the bullet
\renewcommand{\thebullet}{[\arabic{bullet}]}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first item \bulletlabel{first}

    \item second item
\end{itemize}

In \ref{first} we find the first item.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks perfect, thanks! I'm sure it will help other people too.

Comment: @Jeroen great, glad it helped :)